# Create class structure like glide and picasso in android

Tags: java, android, oop

I want to create class structure like:

```
Glide.with(context).load("url").into(imageView);
```

**Problem :-**

> ```
> public class Slider{
>
>     private static Activity context;
>     private static int Duration = 3000;
>
>     public static void setContext(Activity context) {
>         Slider.context = context;
>     }
>
>     public static void setDuration(Duration duration) {
>         Slider.Duration = duration;
>     }
> }
> // In Activity
> Slider.setContext(this);
> ```

- I declared all methods and required fields static but it can't work.
- I tried with setter method but it allows only one setter.This class doesn't allow me to use second setter.

**Requirement :**

```
Slider.setContext(this).setDuration(3000);
```

I need class and method structure like [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) library and some methods are compulsory.

Comment: What is the problem? Any code reference?

Comment: i need class structure like this : "Slider.setContext(this).setDuration(3000)"

Comment: I have posted an answer

Comment: If you can tell your use case, we can lead you better.

Comment: Builder pattern for declare code like this : Slider.setContext(this).setDuration(3000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Builder Pattern** for this

```
public class Slider
{
    private static Activity context;
    private static int Duration = 3000;

    private Slider(SliderBuilder builder) {
        this.context = builder.context;
        this.Duration = builder.Duration;
    }

    //All getter, and NO setter to provde immutability
    public String getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    public String getDuration() {
        return Duration;
    }

    public static SliderBuilder with(Activity context){
        return new SliderBuilder(context);
    }

    public static class SliderBuilder
    {
        private static Activity context;
        private static int Duration = 3000;

        public SliderBuilder(Activity context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public SliderBuilder duration(int Duration) {
            this.Duration = Duration;
            return this;
        }
        //Return the finally constructed Slider object
        public Slider build() {
            Slider slider =  new Slider(this);
            validateSliderObject(slider);
            return slider;
        }
        private void validateSliderObject(Slider slider) {
            //Do some basic validations to check
        }
    }
}
```

Better explained [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/)

**EDIT**

> How to use

```
Slider.with(this).duration(3000).build();
```

Comment: how to use this class without initialize with "new" keyword?

Comment: @BhautikKeraliya I have modified my answer according to the requirement. Please check

Comment: How to declare force usable method?

Comment: @BhautikKeraliya you can use `validateSliderObject` method to see if the user has used some method

Comment: i can't understand.

Comment: Please could you explain it.

Comment: when the `build(last)` method is called. An internal method of `SliderBuilder` class `validateSliderObject` will check if the required method is called.

Comment: how to check required method is called or not?

Comment: See if the default value is changed. For example if `Duration` value is changed from `3000`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200004/discussion-between-bhautik-keraliya-and-rahul-khurana).